# Li Ion series Charging and Discharging

Tags: lithium-ion, charging

I have 3 Li-ion cell of 2000 mAh. I want to charge them in series and with charging I want to connect load with it load is of 1 A and charger which I am using is of 2000 mAh, 12.6 volts. Does it make any harm to the batteries? One more thing it will be plugged in for 24/7.

Comment: What is the voltage rating of single lion cell battery?

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Answer (score 1):

Fully charging LiIon batteries involves 4 phases of alterning constant current with constant voltage (see second link below). However, if you keep charging at "slow rates", it's easier:

- Charge at constant current of 0.18C or less.
- Stop when battery outputs 4.2V. It's charged around 70% to 80%.
- When battery outputs 3V, it's considered discharged. Going below this value may harm it.
- Your batteries hold 2000mAh, therefore C=2000mA, therefore the "slow rate" charging current should be 360mA or less.

See:

- http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?294844-Charging-Lithium-Batteries%97rather-Balanced-and-in-Series-or-Parallel
- http://www.powerstream.com/li.htm
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Li-ion-battery-charging/

It is unwise to charge LiIon batteries in series if you only check the total output voltage (12.6V). Due to slight differences between batteries, even of the same made and manufacturer, some of the batteries will be charged more than others, and go beyond the safety mark of 4.2V.

Usually you use a balancer to prevent this problem. Depending on your goal (are you building an [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) of some sort?) you may prefer to have the batteries in parallel, and use a Boost converter to raise the output voltage.

To anwer your questions directly:

- LiIon cells of 2000 mAh, even of C=1, are able to provide 2A continous. So you're within safe limits with your load.
- A 'charger' can be of lots of types. If charger is LiIon prepared, then it looks right. If 'charger' is just a power source of 12.6V, the you can't use it. It will force way too much current into your battery pack, without caring about slow rate or charging phases.

Comment: From where i can buy the boost conerter or make it ... i want to boost the volatge from 3.7 volts 12 amps to 12 volts and 2 amps

Comment: I can't really advise you, as I don't know what application you intend to build. If you look for DC to DC converters over internet you will find lots of different solutions from DIY to commercial ready to plug ones. For example: http://www.vicorpower.com/dcm-ChiP

Comment: Glad I've helped. If you wish, you could validate my answer.